# DbUpdateConcurrencyException on inserting a new row in SQL Server using EF Core (expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s))

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to insert data in one table using Ef core 5 with repository pattern and Unit of work.

Code Sample :

```
               var stateData = new State
                {
                    StateId = state.StateId,
                    Action = state.Action,
                    Event = state.Event,
                    ExecutedOn = DateTime.Now
                };
                _unitOfWork.GetRepository<State>().Add(stateData);
                var result = _unitOfWork.Commit();
```

GetRepository method used to get respective repo:

```
        {
            return (IRepository<TEntity>)GetOrAddRepository(typeof(TEntity), new 
             Repository<TEntity>(Context));
        }
```

Commit Method :

```
        {
            return Context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I am trying to insert data in state table which has Id as primary and identity column. Rest other columns are StateId,Action,Event and ExecutedOn(datatype : datetime2).

Application is running on multiple nodes. So there will be multiple insert request at a same time from multiple node but different data.

I am getting DbUpdateConcurrencyException frequently while inserting the records of states in DB. Sometimes it works but most of time I get DbUpdateConcurrencyException with message "Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions".

There is no update operation but still I am getting concurrency exception.

I have tried all others solutions on similar questions but no luck.

Comment: Get rid of Unit of work.

Comment: @Serge I don't think it is due to Unit of work thing. I will try without unit of work. I don't know why concurrency exception is there as every time there is new record to insert. For Update operation I can understand concurrency thing should be there. But not sure why I am getting it on insert.